# Передача параметра из View в javascript функцию, и далее в Controller

Tags: asp.net, ajax, mvc, dojo, javascript

Пишу на asp.net mvc + dojo.
Во вьюхе есть грид,  у которого есть событие

```
function onGridClick(event) {             
    var selectedIndex = grid.focus.rowIndex;
    var selectedItem = grid.getItem(selectedIndex);
    selectedId = grid.store.getValue(selectedItem, 'id');
}
```

Кроме того, имеется кнопочка для удаления записи:

```
<button id="btnDel" dojotype="dijit.form.Button" onclick="DeleteDoc(selectedId)">
                Удалить</button>
```

По нажатию кнопки срабатывает функция с ajax-скриптом:

```
function DeleteDoc(selectedId)
{
    alert(selectedId.toString());

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: '../Index/DeleteDoc',
      data: { 'selectedId' : selectedId},
    success: function (msg) {
       alert(msg);

    },
    error: function (request, status, error) {
            alert('Ошибка запроса к серверу');
            return false;
      }
    });
}
```

Ну и метод в контроллере:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult DeleteDoc(int selectedId)
{
    DOCS currentDoc = database.DOCS.First(x => x.ID == selectedId);
    database.DOCS.DeleteObject(currentDoc);
    database.SaveChanges();
    string msg = "Complete!";
    return Json(msg);
}
```

Проблема - не срабатывает метод `success` у ajax скрипта. 
`Alert` срабатывает, а идет дальше выполнение или нет я не знаю.

Выполняю отладку через студию, грешу на строку **url: '../Index/DeleteDoc'**.
Изначально было так - **url: 'Index/DeleteDoc'**

Comment: И иетод error тоже не срабатыват? (+ что говорит FireBug или WebTools?)

Comment: И еррор тоже не срабатывает.
Фаирбаг ничего не говорит.

Хотя может быть я не там смотрю (занимаюсь вебом 2-ую неделю, все тонкости отладки пока не известны).

Comment: Вопрос решен. В силу своей неопытности пытался таким образом передать значение переменной из яваскрипта в контроллер шарпа.
Решением явилась передача hidden полю значения из скрипта через document.getelementbyid.